# Colorbox stopped working

Tags: colorbox

I recently have an issue with colorbox. After moving the site in different server (cloud) the functionality of opening a link with colorbox, stopped working. The files are the same and I have not changed anything. 
Do you have any suggestions? Is there any server compatibility that I have to look around?
Thanks in advance,
Penny.

Comment: Are you sure you are still pointing at the right location and that all files are there? Can you share a link?

Comment: Hello Ares, yes I just copy/paste the files of my project into the new server. I cannot share the link as it is in the administration menu of a live site. I was just wondering if there is a known compatibility issues with colorbox and cloud servers.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Colorbox, and all jQuery and Javascript scripts for that matter, are client-based. This means it is the client (the visitor's computer) who does all the work. The server has absolutely nothing to do with them. This being said, the answer of to your questions is: no. There are no know (or even unknown) compatibility issues with colorbox and any time of server.

So, more than likely something went wrong with your files when you migrated to your new server.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought, I was just asking for ensuring it! Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: @user2161111 if this is the answer to your question you should mark it as so

Comment: I'm familiar with the client based technology, I was just asking if someone else has experienced the same issue with colorbox that suddenly stopped working. I have copied all the server files local and the project is working just fine as it used to. Anyways, thanks again.